# How to avoid update errors NU3018 in VS2019?

Tags: nuget-package, visual-studio-2019

I want to update packages puts to each update I have the following error:

**Severity Code Description Project File Line Delete Status Delete Status
Error NU3018 Package 'jQuery 3.4.1' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': Repository main signature found a string generation problem: A certificate chain has been processed but ended with a root certificate that is not trusted by the trust provider.**

I tried with the console and as an adminstrator but still the same error